# How to shoot B&W images in SONY Cyber Shot DSC-H70?

Tags: sony, black-and-white

What's the best way to take black and white images with a [Sony Cyber-shot DSC-H70](http://www.sony.co.uk/product/dsc-h-series/dsc-h70)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it think the best way getting black/white images is to shot them in color (RAW if available) and make them b/w in your favorite postprocessing tool.

RAW would have the advantage, that you can gain more details from for example the sky or clouds.

Comment: the premade black and white from your camera most time is not that what you expect from a  black and white. adding contrast would help to get what you want. you will find a lot of tutorials how to create black and white pictures, or high contrast black and white.

Answer (score 2):

It must quite surprising but the truth is that Sony **skipped the B&W capture feature** in many Digital cameras like DSC-H70, DSC W510, etc.

Some models with this feature are DSC-W80/W85/W90;

Even the in-camera editor won't allow you to apply B&W filter.

Obviously you are left with single but best option: **Shoot in color and convert to B&W on post-production**.